# Can't see output of Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have such dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD "Hello docker!"
ENTRYPOINT echo
```

I build image as following:

```
docker build -t mydocker .
```

Then I run it:

```
docker run --name mydocker1 -t mydocker
```

But as output I see only empty string, I exptected to see "`Hello docker1`" though.
I tried to also:

```
docker logs mydocker1
```

It gives me empty string too.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: try `sleep infinity` as your CMD and ENTRYPOINT both complete immediately, so your container exits

Comment: @user2915097 I should add `CMD sleep infinity` at the end of the dockerfile?

Comment: you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it in the following manner :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
CMD ["Hello docker!"]
ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
```